# After registration redirect to login page in laravel 8 jetstream

Tags: laravel-8

I want to redirect the user after registration in laravel 8 jetstream to login page or welcome page.
How can i do this?

Comment: You can add redirect to route after register user in `RegisteredUserController@store()`

Answer (score 0):

Well in Fortify the user gets Authenticated Automatically then you can change the location of this in your config/fortify.php

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Home Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the path where users will get redirected during
    | authentication or password reset when the operations are successful
    | and the user is authenticated. You are free to change this value.
    |
    */

    'home' => RouteServiceProvider::HOME,
```